# iPhone 6s battery issues

Tags: iphone, performance

My iPhone 6s sometimes suddenly goes to **1 - 10%** and sometimes **70 - 80%** after restarting. Sometimes my iPhone works for 4 - 5 hours and sometimes 100% goes down to 10% in 1 hour or less. What is this problem? Is there a battery issue or issue with software? Should I go to some repairing shop or sell it?

I have seen so many question like this but non of them are giving a correct answer for my problem. I've never experienced this type of issue in my any phone but iPhone 6s is not working fine for me.

Here are few problems that I am facing:

- Battery automatically goes down in few minutes.
- Auto-Restart.
- Freeze sometimes.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) How long have you been using your iPhone? What is the version of iOS running on your iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

A reasonable explanation would be that the battery of your iPhone has come of age. Try to access the battery health (completed charge cycles, charge holding capacity etc.) using a popular battery assessment tool called [coconutBattery](https://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/).

Batteries has a fixed number of charge cycles and post consuming them, the charge holding capacity deteriorates.

It is also advisable to keep the iOS software up-to-date. Having it up-to-date alleviates any software related glitches that may be causing trouble with the hardware/battery.

Post analysis, if you feel that the battery is showing signs of going kaput, you can choose to go for a replacement.